# Can google appengine's admin console be integrated into a spring-boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When running a normal appengine project using `mvn appengine:run` I see this line 
`[INFO] INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin`
appear in the boot-up sequence and I am able to access a local console for datastore at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin

When running a spring-boot project on appengine using `mvn spring-boot:run` there is no such line and no local datastore console.

How can I integrate the admin server that produces this console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Admin console, you will need to use the "[java_dev_appserver](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-local-server#running)", probably in a new tab in the shell.

Note that this will be deprecated and instead you will be expected to use the [Datastore emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#starting_the_emulator), which does not have a GUI console yet.